# how to get bitbucket tagged commits sorted by date-wise using Bitbucket API?

Tags: git, bitbucket, bitbucket-server, bitbucket-api, bitbucket-cloud

I am working on a project that needs to fetch all tagged commits sorted in reverse order by datetime.
I first tried using this API **/2.0/repositories/{workspace}/{slug}/refs/tags** but the results are in random order which i believe is sorted in asc by name.

However I am able to get results in sorted manner by name in desc using **/2.0/repositories/{workspace}/{slug}/refs/tags?sort=-name** But when I use updated_on  , date or datetime I get this error

```
{
    "type": "error",
    "error": {
        "message": "Invalid field name: date"
    }
}
```

I can have the expected results by writing some code but can we get same through bitbucket API ?

Answer (score 4):

Try `target.date`

```
/2.0/repositories/{workspace}/{slug}/refs/tags?sort=-target.date
```